# Configurate doctrine_migration_versions table in custom schema instead of public

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-migrations

Is there a way for the automatic `doctrine_migration_versions`to be stored in a schema other than `public`?

Right now I have a schema called `inschrijving` and all the entities properties are stored as tables and columns within that schema, but not the doctrine migration versions table.

Here's how my entities are stored:
[image]

And the `doctrine_migration_versions` is stored in the `public` schema:
[image]

I cannot find anywhere how to configure doctrine in order for the **doctrine_migration_versions** to be stored within the **inschrijving** schema instead of the **public** schema

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it myself by asking in another forum, but if anyone is interested:

```
doctrine_migrations:
    storage:
        # Default (SQL table) metadata storage configuration
        table_storage:
            table_name: 'inschrijving.doctrine_migration_versions'
```

You will need to create the schema manually in the db before applying migrations, though.

```
CREATE SCHEMA inschrijving;
```

And then

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

And it should look like this:
[image]

Comment: Nice find @Ari! But, independently of this, does it make sense to keep these two separated?

Comment: @JovanPerovic thanks, wdym with "these two" seperated?

Comment: I mean for tables to be in one schema and migrations data in another?

Comment: @JovanPerovic no it doesn't make sense, but that's why I asked the question