# No table with name "doctrine_migration_versions" in the schema

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-migrations

I have an application that uses Doctrine to manage its migrations. This has worked well during development, but when trying to deploy the application on a fresh database, the migration command fails.

I can run the database creation command successfully:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists
```

This connects to the database and can both create the database, or check that it exists and skip. So this is not a connection issue, etc.

The next command, however, fails:

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

It throws the error on the title of this question:

```
In TableDoesNotExist.php line 16:
                                                                            
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Exception\TableDoesNotExist (10)]                   
  There is no table with name "doctrine_migration_versions" in the schema.
```

I'm pretty new to Doctrine in general, so it's unclear to me what this error is even complaining about. How can I fix it? Is this a configuration problem on the fresh environment?

Comment: have you tried with the command php bin/console doctrine:migrations:version --add --all

Comment: Tried it just now, but it gives me the same error. Every command I've tried in the `migrate` namespace has failed with the same issue

Comment: see if this helps you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70672865/configurate-doctrine-migration-versions-table-in-custom-schema-instead-of-public

Comment: I did see that before, but I'm not sure it's related to my problem. I'm happy using the default doctrine behaviour, I'm not trying to customise anything. Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a permissions issue. I couldn't find in the Doctrine docs any mention of which permissions the DB user required, but granting all privileges on the configured database sorted out the issue:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_database.* TO 'my_user'@'%';
```